# JavaScript Alert message not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Below is the code that I have put together to validate 5 fields, of a form that has like 9 fields, that are to be required. I created the variables and placed them into an array.  From there I have a function that loops through this array to see pop up an alert if that field is left blank.

The problem that I am coming across is that the alerts are not popping up when the button is clicked.

```
var uName=document.getElementByName('userName');
var pword=document.gelElementByName('password');
var verify=document.getElementByName('passwordVerify');
var fName=document.getElementByName('firstName');
var lName=document.getElementByName('lastName');
var field=[uName,pword,verify,fName,lName];

function validateForm(form) {
  for(var i = 0; i < form.field.length; i++){
    if(form.field[i].value.length == 0){
       alert(form.field[i].name+' is required. Please populate');
       form.field[i].focus();
       return false;
    }
   } return true;
}
```

Not sure what I did wrong or what is causing the error.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No such thing as `getElementByName` or `gelElementByName`. Spelling matters. Better to use `querySelector` if you want to select a single element

Comment: Please add full code

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: There is getElementsByName (plural), but querySelector may be better, as @CertainPerformace mentioned.MDN:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateForm() {
  var uName = document.getElementById('userName');
  var pword = document.getElementById('password');
  var verify = document.getElementById('passwordVerify');
  var fName = document.getElementById('firstName');
  var lName = document.getElementById('lastName');
  var field = [uName, pword, verify, fName, lName];

  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    if (!field[i].value) {
      alert(field[i].name + ' is required. Please populate');
      field[i].focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="passwordVerify" name="passwordVerify" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" /><br/>
  <button onclick="validateForm();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, here are the changes I made:

I changed `getElementByName` to `getElementById` throughout your code, for simplicity;
I removed the function's parameter, and changed `form.field` to `field` because... Well, the first one was just wrong.

I also changed the iterating test to `!field[i].value`, which is equivalent to testing if the value has a length, but seemed more appropriate to me.

That's about all I did, along with adding ID's to the form's elements.

---

P.S: That is my first detailed answer here, feedback would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: It's a complete answer, explanation and code... to be even better, always try (if possible) to put the code inside a snippet for easy test, using the `<>` button

Comment: @Calvin Could you please elaborate on that? Private Messaging or anything else if OK to me, but I don't really have a testing field for this snippet feature :)

Comment: you know where to edit your answer? if yes, click there, you will see the toolbar with buttons such as B (for bold) I (for italic), etc... there's a button with this symbol: `<>`, click in it. it will open a window where you can add HTML, JS, CSS separated and you can attach the code there. So this code will be executed everytime you click on "Run" and even after attaching it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll do that just now

Comment: I tried that update and I get to where the alert window pops up but it shows nothing.  When I look at the developer tools it comes back with the following message:

Uncaught TypeError: field[i].focus is not a function
    at reqField (formvalidate.js:15)

Should i look to set the focus outside of the loop?  Sorry for the questions, I am new to the JS language.  It is a little different than what I am familiar with.

Comment: I think you might want to look into jQuery for focusing on a field, I have no idea on how to do it in pure JS. But jQuery is out of my knowledge, sadly :/